# how do I redirect from one page to another with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All the advice online says do:
rewrite 301 URL-A URL-B

But that won't work if I turn on mod_rewrite (it seems?) with RewriteEngine on

So, I'm bad a regex, but shouldn't need it here.  How do I do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^untamed-adventures.com/travel/How/tabid/58/Default.aspx [NC] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://untamed-adventures.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` expands to the host of the request, so it could never match `untamed-adventures.com/travel/How/tabid/58/Default.aspx`, only `untamed-adventures.com`.

If you want to forward `http://untamed-adventures.com/travel/How/tabid/58/Default.aspx` to `http://untamed-adventures.com/`, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =untamed-adventures.com
RewriteRule ^/travel/How/tabid/58/Default.aspx$ http://untamed-adventures.com/ [R=301]
```

The `L` flag is redundant; a forward is always final.

Comment: Ah, the RewriteRule bit works except one must drop the leading /
Cheers very much!

Comment: @Dan only if in a .htaccess or if you've set `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Ah ha!  Yes, was in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all clear what you're trying to do. HTTP_HOST is the hostname part in the requested URL, in this case, "untamed-adventures.com", so that RewriteCond will never match.

I *think* that what you're trying to do is:

Redirect 301 /travel/How/tabid/58/Default.aspx http://untamed-adventures.com/

In which case, mod_rewrite isn't needed at all.

Comment: There are other instructions in the file that require mod_rewrite.